# DSI 7inch touchscreen does not work anymore

Tags: touchscreen, dsi

I have 2x 7inch touchscreens laying here. (Original raspberry touchscreens)
I always had one connected to a raspberry. The other one was backup. After I connected the backup one to the raspberry, my SD card went corrupt.

Now I tried everything to get one of the two touchscreens working with a fresh install of raspbian. Both don't work. 
Tried updating raspbian etc. Nothing has worked. 
The DSI boards don't have a light so I can't see if they are broken.

The raspberry does not recognize them with:

```
dmesg | grep -i ft5406
```

So I think it might be the touchscreens that are broken.

Is there anyway to trouble shoot this?

Thankyou, Rick

Comment: I doubt 2 touchscreens would go caboom simultaneously. Most probably the DSI controller on the RPi broke down. Try connecting your screens to a different RPi if you have one.

Comment: Hey Dmitry, thank you for your response!
Tried it with 3 different raspberry 3's. I did connect 5v and gnd turned on the wrong connections. But I thought they would have protection for that.

Comment: Measure voltage on your raspberry pins first.

Answer (score 0):

Might be work checking you have the cable the right way round though as it's not obvious (to me at least) which way round it's supposed to go.

I agree with the commenter that it's unlikely both screens would fail at once. Best way to confirm is to get a second PI and test with that, as it could be your DSI socket has failed (unusual, but not impossible).

I know Pis are hard to get hold of right now, but there are some reasonably priced second hand Pi 2s to be had on ebay.  Although original Pis have a DSI port, I'd not recommend them for testing as I've had issues getting DSI to work at all on an original A+.  I do have a Waveshare DSI display running fine on a Pi2 though, so you'd probably be OK with one of those.

Answer (score -1):

Check to make sure you plugged them into the right pins and that the connections are secure.  If you didn't, there's a chance that you could have destroyed them.

Comment: It's a DSI connected screen - no pins to misalign.